# AngularJS - how to execute code in module.run section

Tags: angularjs

I tried to google this, but couldn't find anything helpful.

index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
...
    <script src="/script/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/script/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/script/app_module.js"></script>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

and app_module.js like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.run(function() {
    console.log("app run");
});
```

And I don't get any console output.
Btw I tried the same thing in jsfiddle and it worked perfectly.

I'm confused. Any ideas why it doesn't run?

AngularJS 1.4

Comment: Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: Also check the network tab on the developer tools, be sure that the js files are being loaded.

Comment: should work fine if paths are correct

Comment: Try wrapping your code in app_module.js with $(document).ready fn

Comment: @TlonXP yea, they're loading, cause I tried to console.log outside the run block, and it worked

Comment: @nikhil wrapping angular module code in `$()` is just not right and makes no sense at all

Comment: @charlietfl - I agree. I just want to rule out the order of execution cause.

Comment: @charlietfl it should. but it's not

Comment: well something else is wrong that isn't being shown in code above. Without a way to replicate this all anyone here can do is guess

Comment: Try adding <!doctype html>.

Comment: @ChrisHermut oh, it is there. I doubt it could be the case, but I'll edit the question

Comment: I've asked because a while back I've been reading about an issue when doctype was missing (can't recall any specifics). Just to double check.

Comment: @charlietfl but how can something else affect the run block? everything but this works fine. so I really don't see how something as simple as console log inside a run block can go wrong, since it's the first thing to be executed. well, after the config block, which is not present in my script.

Comment: no idea unless somewhere else console.clear() is called perhaps. Put a breakpoint on the run block

Comment: ok. I got it. the problem was in the `var app = angular.module('app', []);` line repeating in the begining of my second script file. I didn't know it could be the case, so I apologize for not mentioning it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is brought here by the same situation,

The problem was in the `var app = angular.module('app', []);` line repeating in the begining of my second script file.

After removing it from there and leaving only in the begining of `app_module.js` (as mentioned in the question), problem disappeared.

to set 'app' variable in the second file, used `angular.module('app', []).run( ... )` in the first one, and, when setting variable in the second file, set it like `var app = angular.module('app');`. Without the second argument, since module is already registered.

Comment: Try `angular.module("app").run(...)` without the second arg.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `/` at the beginning of your `src` will ensures that the path is not relative but `read from the root` of the site.

Remove your starting slashes, the `root` is probably somewhere else, in a parent folder:

```
<script src="script/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script/angular.js"></script>
<script src="script/app_module.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you check if angular is correctly loaded, by using this for eg: 

`if(typeof angular == 'undefined') {
    alert("angular is not loaded");
}`

If you see the alert, your angular isn't correctly loaded